# Taylor expansion of $\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n(1+\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I can't get the right terms:

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + \frac{(-1)^n}n + o(\frac1n)}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} - \frac1{n\ln^2 n}+o\left(\frac1{n\ln^2 n}\right)$$

**My thoughts**

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n(1+\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})}$$
note that 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{1+x}&=1-x+x^2+o(x^2) \\
&=1-x+x^2+O(x^3) 
\end{align*}

we work with  o with $x=\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})$
then  $(1+\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n}))=1-\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})+(\frac{1}{n\ln n}+O(\frac{1}{n\ln n}))^2+o((\frac{1}{n\ln n}+O(\frac{1}{n\ln n})))^2$
finaly
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n(1+\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})}=\frac{ (-1)^n }{ ln(n)( 1-\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})+(\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n}))^2+o((\frac{1}{n\ln n}+o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})))^2 ) ) }=$$

but i'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n\ln n} + o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}\left(1 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n\ln n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n\ln n}\right)\right),$$

which multiplies out to $$\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}  - \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}\right).$$

Comment: could you add some lines to see why we have $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n\ln n} + o(\frac{1}{n\ln n})}=\left(1 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n\ln n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n\ln n}\right)\right), $

Comment: @Educ since $\frac{1}{1 + x} = 1 - x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$, and since both $\frac{(-1)^n}{n\ln n}$ and $\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ tend to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, you get that equation.